# create new android virtual device(AVD)

Tags: android

The OK button is disabled in the window even after selecting all the options in eclipse.
has any one used it before successfully.

I am using ecclipse with android SDK

Comment: More detail would be helpful. And maybe a picture.

Comment: Yes, all of us have used it successfully. Explain the problem better.

Answer (score 0):

There's no error or warning message?

Make sure that you have installed a Android OS Image and had set all fields in the AVD creation screen.

Good luck.

EDIT: Also check if you set a SDK version to your project equal or compatible to a available emulator version.

Answer (score 0):

If you have entered "AVD NAME" and selected both "Device" and "Target" for emulator.

Than check in SDK Manager that you have downloaded at least one single "System Image" for selected "Target" than "OK" button should work.

Answer (score 0):

i just avoided spaces in the AVD name and the issue gor resloved.

Comment: Were you not getting that error message at bottom of AVD creation dialogue? If yes than it's really strange that you missed such obvious point.

Comment: @zeeshan There is no message being displayed at the bottom or any where else for that sake....of course I won't be missing such obvious point. :)